# Is a wildcard certificate necessary in this case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate, ca

We want to secure the connection between all our internal servers, as well as from outside.

A basic diagram in AWS is:

[image]

As I have never installed SSL before, I don't know whether I really need a wildcard certificate, `*.domain.com`, or just a single certificate installed in the load balancer `domain.com` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a certificate which matches all the domains you use. `example.com` only matches `example.com` but neither `www1.example.com` nor `www2.example.com`. This means you need either a certificate containing a wildcard for `*.example.com` or a certificate including both names you need to match as subject alternative names.